# Group query elements by same name in django

Tags: django

I am stuck on this task. My query output is as follows (when list() is used):

```
days=[{'day':1,'do':'paint'},{'day':2,'do':'paint'},{'day':3,'do':'Dry'},{'day':4,'do':'Fubrish'},{'day':5,'do':'Fubrish'},{'day':6,'do':'paint'}]
```

It comes from this model:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):

   day_no = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Number of Day')  # 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
   task = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I basically want to loop thru each and see if there are same 'do' consecutively and store the total number of found occurance. E.g. Day 1 and 2, the user is advised to do painting. Day 3 he does Drying and the next 2 days to Fubrish then again paint.

I want an output that will basically say:

```
paint: 2
dry: 1
fubrish: 2
paint: 1
```

I did play on my jupyter but it is errorful:

```
tasks={}

total=len(days)

for i in range(0,total):
    day = days[i]['day']
    do = days[i]['do']

if i == 0:
    tasks[do]=1
else:
    if i+1 < total:
        if days[i+1]['do'] == do:  # the next one is same as current one
            tasks[do] = len(tasks) + 1
        else:
            if tasks.get(do, None) != None:
                tasks[do] = len(tasks) + 1
            else:
                tasks = {}
                tasks[do] = 1
```

Comment: Please post your model.

Comment: added my model @alfonso.kim

Comment: @NieSelam try my code that is  few lines and will work because that's the way of django  {% regroup %} templatetag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
def func(task_list):
    if len(task_list) == 0:
        return
    current = task_list[0]['do']
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(task_list)):
        new_task = task_list[i]['do']
        if new_task == current:
             count+=1
        else:
             print '%s: %d' %(current, count)
             count = 1
        current = new_task
    print '%s: %d' %(current, count)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work for your requirement.

```
    from itertools import groupby

    data = [{'grouper': key, 'list': list(group)} for key, group in groupby(queryset, lambda x: getattr(x, 'do')
    for d in data:
        print d['grouper'], len(d['list')
```

Pass **queryset** to this above line and also edit **field name** in last that you want. it will give output as **django templatetag** {% regroup %} tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: Hey @NeErAj KumaR thats quite insightful. I did try it out of curiosity and it works as expected but my current need is not in template. Am sure we will reach that stage tho.

Comment: but you can also use in view

Answer (score 0):

You can also use defaultdict and code below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
results = []
prev_task = defaultdict(int)
for d in days:
    curr_task = d['do']
    if curr_task not in prev_task and len(prev_task) > 0:
        results.append(dict(prev_task))
        prev_task.clear()
    prev_task[curr_task] += 1
    if d is days[-1]:
        # if this is the last item
        results.append(dict(prev_task))
```